# How to streams video file from m3u8 file in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

currently i am developing an live video streaming app in windows phone. My problem is that i can't play the .m3u8 file in windows phone .How can read and play the .m3u8 file?

please give me a solution for this..

thanks

Comment: as of now i am trying to develop video streaming using the SMOOTH STREMAING SERVER  & IIS server.but the video is not working for me . i don't know the issue ..any one have experience in this please help me i am referring this blog for implementing streaming ..http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/smooth-streaming-on-windows-phone-7/

Comment: See here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005883/playing-hls-m3u8-playlist-on-windows-phone-8-1/27026663#27026663

Answer (score 0):

.m3u8 is a format supported by APPLE.

Unfortunately we cannot play the m3u8 files on windows phone directly.

Rather we can use the streaming media framework to play .manifest files. The .manifest files are generated by the SMOOTH STREAMING MEDIA SERVER. .manifest files are equivalent of m3u8 files. It is also a playlist file just like the m3u8 file.

SMOOTH STREMAING SERVER, is a part of windows media servies that works on a IIS server.